# tracking and showing mouse position jquery php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to track and play the mouse pointer like a movie is playing. i have already tracked the mouse position and stored in my database. but i am unable to show these mouse positions like a movie. its showing the mouse movement, but not the way in which i have recorded.

```
 <script>
 var xdata = <?php echo json_encode($xdata); ?>;
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $("#clickme").click(function() {

 for (var i=0; i<=xdata['x'].length-1; i++){

    lpos = xdata['x'][i];
    tpos = xdata['y'][i];
    $("#mouse_pointer").animate({ 
    'top': tpos+'px',
    'left': lpos+'px',      
  }, 200 );
 }

});

});


</script>
```

following is the mouse positions stored during tracking.

```
PosX    PosY   duration (milliseconds)
306     25     935
308     25     8
312     25     7
316     25     20
320     25     391
324     25     41
325     2      5
328     38     34
```

Can anyone please help ??? is it the right method ???

Comment: If you print the coordinates within your `onclick` function to the console, do they show correctly?

Comment: yeah its showing all the values in the console. is animate is the right function to use show the previously recorded mouse positions ?

Comment: `animate` should work fine for that purpose. Is it possible that the coordinates were taken from another "scope" than you try to animate them later? As in, did you perhaps measure coordinates on the screen and animate them within a `<div>` element so now they are off by some constant value?

Comment: yeah, its working fine now. thank you. actually i was storing the coordinates in mysql, i think it was losing some coordinates while insertion. one more think, can i use milliseconds in animate function, because i wants to show the mouse stop or speed as well.